# Default memberwise initializer with lazy property

Tags: swift

If I have a struct with a lazy property, Swift expects the default memberwise initializer to include that property, even though it's not settable.

For example:

```
struct Lazy {
       let id: String
       lazy var greeting: String = { "hello" }()
}
```

Swift requires:

```
var lazy = Lazy(id: "MINE", greeting: "goodbye")
```

but ignores the lazy input:

```
print(lazy.greeting) // "hello"
```

Am I correct in understanding that this is a Swift bug?

EDIT:

As the commenters have pointed out, I was incorrect in assuming the `lazy var` is not settable. However, it still seems there are unintuitive semantics here. Such a variable does have a value as soon as it is accessed.

Similarly, it strikes me as odd that computed `let` properties are not included in the memberwise initializer, but computed `var`s are.

Comment: Already tracked as https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-3059.

Comment: However, your code prints "goodbye" in my test, so the initial value is *not* ignored.

Comment: "Swift expects the default memberwise initializer to include that property, even though it's not settable" there's no such thing as a not settable lazy stored property, since lazy properties get a value assigned to them the first time they are accessed. Due to this, lazy properties are by default settable and gettable.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks for that link! Interesting to learn that this behavior is "by design" -- my thinking was too narrow on this.

Comment: @DávidPásztor Good point ... I'm glad I asked, because I learned my own misconception about lazy properties!